# XSD No Data Tag, Self Closing, Empty?

Tags: xml, xsd, tags, validation

I have seen a few answers to self closing tags in XSD, but non included empty definitions.

I have a large XML document that is automatically generated by a program.

The XML is similar to this:

```
<START>
<ON/>
<item1>
<item2>
<I data1="" data2="">
<I info1="" info2="">
</I>
</item2>
</item1>
</START>
```

For the tag named "ON", because it is self close and does not contain any data, how is this written in my XSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XSD :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="START">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ON"/>
                <xs:element ref="item1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="item1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <!-- more declarations follow here -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!-- more declarations follow here -->
</xs:schema>
```

Also notice that in your XML `<ON/>` could as well be `<ON></ON>` and you'd have the same XSD. `<ON/>` is an empty element in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for that, was unsure with declaring an empty element. I am now trying to loop through the same xml but I only want to gather the attribute data, what are you thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you describe which programming language and XML APIs you're using ?